# move files up one level and purge subfolder

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

i am trying to crate a batch to move all files in a specific folder up one level and then purge the old subfolder. My understanding is that i could use robocopy to copy the files then move them up a level, and use /purge to remove the subfolder. but i am getting an error '%%s unexpected at this time'... not sure where to go from here

```
for /f "delims=|" %%s in ('dir /ad/b') do robocopy "\\server\e$\dir1\dir2\%%s\dir3\dir4" "\\server\e$\dir1\dir2\dir3" /E /MOVE /PURGE
```

Comment: Are you running from batch file or command prompt?

Comment: Note that `%s` is used only in command prompt, while `%%s` is used in batch files.

Comment: Thanks, i had also taking that into consideration while testing.... same error, hence my question.